# The script does not work with token validation in php

Tags: php

The script does not work with token validation in php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
};
if($_POST['token']==$_SESSION['token']){
  session_destroy();
  header('location: ../index.php');
};

?>
```

```
<form action="configs/logout.php" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php $_SESSION['token']; ?>">
   <button class="nav-link" type="submit">LogOut</button>
</form>
```

But if I remove the token validation, everything works. It seems to me that this is due to the fact that session_destroy is triggered before the check for the token is triggered.

And do you need token verification for security when logout? Laravel adds it for all forms, so I decided to do it too.

UPD. I also tried to do this (with unset), but as in the first case, it simply goes to the configs / logout.php tab and nothing happens:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
};
if($_POST['token']==$_SESSION['token']){
  unset($_SESSION['user']);
  header('location: ../index.php');
};

?>
```

`$_SESSION['user']` - appears when the user is authorized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `value="<?php $_SESSION['token']; ?>"` in your form to this:

```
value="<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>"
```

In form you forget add `echo`